# JPA Criteria - how to use EXTRACT(field FROM timestamp)?

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

There is a

```
<T> Expression<T>   function(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Class<T> type, Expression<?>... args)
```

The method in `CriteriaBuilder`, that allows to

> Create an expression for the execution of a database function.

Nice. So I can, for instance, extract hour from a timestamp:

```
Expression<Integer> year = cb.function("YEAR", Integer.class, root.get("tstamp"));
```

But how to wrap the SQL equivalent of

```
SELECT EXTRACT(ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK FROM tstamp) FROM myTable
```

? Is it possible at all? I need to group by day of the week, so I need to do this at DB level.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL function extract(? from ?) is wrapper around native function 'date_part' which takes two parameters text and date/time/timestamp/interval. This mean you can call:

```
Expression<Integer> year = cb.function("date_part", Integer.class, cb.literal('HOUR'), root.get("tstamp"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cb.function("TO_CHAR",root.get("tstamp"),cb.literal("DD")));
```